# Why is the height of my image not relative to the width?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive website. So, I've got an image width a width that is determined by the with of the page as shown in the snippet. Normally, to keep the aspect ratio, I would just say: 
`height: relative`

But for some reason, the height does not adjust when making the width smaller.. why is that?

```css
/* TITLE BLOCK */

.title_block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  height: auto;
}

.title-block-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 345px;
  height: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="title_block" name="title_block" class="title_block white">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="height: 135px;" class="title-block-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

For responsive websites I use a media query:

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

}

The normal settings of the image are these:

```
.title_block{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title-block-image{
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Might it be that I have to unset the 100px or something? Or should the new `height: auto` already do so?

Comment: there is no `height: relative`  in css!

Comment: can't you just remove height: relative, and add height: auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments there is no `height: relative;` in css. If you want to save the ration you can leave the height because its default value is **auto** or if you previously set images height, you can set for this image: `height: auto;`

Comment: the height still does not adjust.. I don't know how I've ever come up with relative.. but the image still is misshaped

Comment: Did you removed `height: relative` ?

Comment: How you change the width of image? by changing the browser width?

Comment: You must remove this: `style="height: 135px;"` in your image tag. I did not see this firstly. This overrides others height styles for this image.

Comment: that did the job! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, replace height with auto in order to make the image height normal. In addition remove the height attribute in your html as it is overriding your css.

```css
/* TITLE BLOCrelative;K */

.title_block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  height: auto;
}

.title-block-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 345px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="title_block" name="title_block" class="title_block white">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AoYz4Sw.jpg" alt="logo" class="title-block-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `height: relative` in css. But there is `auto`.

What you should do is

CSS:

```
/* TITLE BLOCK */

.title_block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 320px;
  height: auto;
}

.title-block-image {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 345px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 135px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

And in HTML

```
<div id="title_block" name="title_block" class="title_block white">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="{ROOT}img/Camerashop24/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="title-block-image">
  </div>
</div>
```